# update database with jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i try to update/edit using jquery and then save it to database with the help of php

the problem is ***i cant pass the new data to php*** or ***php didnt receive data from jquery***

here is my **form**

```
<form method="POST" name="postForm" action="update.php">
<div id="edit">
First name:<input type="text" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>">
</div>
</form>
<button id="button">Edit</button>
```

and this is my script of *jquery*

```
jQuery("#edit").dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "update.php",
                    async:true,
                    data: { dataToUpdate: jQuery('#edit').attr('value') }
                });
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                jQuery(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
});

// Link to open the dialog
jQuery("#button").click(function(event) {
    jQuery("#edit").dialog("open");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and this is my **PHP**

```
  $id = $_GET['id']; // i dont know if i should put it or not to identify the info i want to edit
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

  $sql = "UPDATE info SET
        firstname='$firstname' WHERE id=$id";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: First of all do not use mysql_* functions anymore. They are marked as deprecated and in PHP7 they are completely removed. After that your sql query is vulnerable and not secure at all. Please make sure that the values to insert are escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the `name` attribute in your form's `input` tag that's why PHP didn't receive the variable...

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>">
```

Or make sure you are passing the value properly using JQuery.

Comment: so this is what should i put on `data: { "firsname":jQuery("#firstname").val()}` ? how about my **PHP** is it correct does it receive the post?

Comment: It should. remove the `dataType: "json"` from jquery.

Comment: Yes its proper. You need an ID as well in order to determine which row you need to update and also follow @Marcel's comment and its important...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here: `data: { dataToUpdate: jQuery('#edit').attr('value') }`

Correct: `data: { firstname: $('#firstname').val() }`

Now it should works

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#edit').attr('value') }
```

it's div that doesn't contain value attribute, use this selector:

```
jQuery('#edit').attr('firstname')
```

Comment: Whoops!!, it should be jQuery('#firstname').attr('value')

Comment: how about this one `data: { "firsname":jQuery("#firstname").val()}` ? is it correct too?

Answer (score 0):

i got it the correct answer for this is i change the

```
data: { dataToUpdate: jQuery('#edit').attr('value') }
```

of **jQuery script** into

```
data: { "firsname":jQuery("#firstname").val()}
```